# Select "umbraco item" using razor

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, umbraco

I want to write a razor macro ***MySelectMacro*** that selects which **umbraco:item** to be rendered.

my simple structure for this case is two pages **-MasterPage and TextPage-** 
and the TextPage contains two fields of type rich-text editor **-field_1 and field_2-**

this is my try which don't work,

Here is the **TextPage** template:

```html
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="MainPageContent" runat="server">
        <umbraco:Macro Alias="MySelectMacro" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

and here is the macro **MySelectMacro**:

```html
@if (condition)
{
    <umbraco:Item field="field_1" runat="server" />
}
else
{
    <umbraco:Item field="field_2" runat="server" />
}
```

*nb: I'm new in umbraco and razors*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use server tags inside your razor template. tags like:

```
<umbraco:Item field="field_1" runat="server" />
```

But you can call

```
@Model.field_1
```

Final version should look like that:

```
@if (condition)
{
    @Model.field_1
}
else
{
    @Model.field_2
}
```

Check this post about razor macros in umbraco: http://www.diplo.co.uk/blog/2011/6/17/using-razor-in-umbraco-47.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Andrei, that's very helpful, but I think you just missed writing '@' before "Model.field_1" in the "Final version"

Comment: Actually since you were already in a code block you don't need the @ on Model ;-) - But glad the OP is up and running!

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled over this answer and for others reading like me: in 2015 and later, it's not `@Model.field` but `@Dictionary["field"]`.

It's explained here:

https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/templating/macros/razor/using-dictionary-items

Anyway, embraced by quota and bracket your field name does not disturb the rest of the ASP script, even if it contains special characters.

Comment: The follow-up question remains open: how to send the `stripParagraph="true"` in the razor script.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix WebForm and Razor syntax!

The equivalent of the old umbraco:item in the new Razor syntax would be:

```
@Umbraco.Field("field_1")
```

You can also pass in various parameters, including the strip paragraph tags flag:

```
@Umbraco.Field("field_1", removeParagraphTags = true)
```